# How to center_vertically text to imageview?

Tags: android, listview

friends,

here is my layout with image and text.

i want to show text vertical align to imageview any one guide me what should i do?
right now it is top align.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bankIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bankName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bankIcon"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textColor="@color/Bank_list_item_color"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort... You've got proper attribute `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in your `ImageView`, just copy it for `TextView`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textview property android:layout_centerInParent="true" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please used below line in TextView..

android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. Add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`
2. Change `android:layout_height` from `wrap_content` to `fill_parent` and add `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bankIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bankName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bankIcon"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textColor="@color/Bank_list_item_color"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```